# Как в таблице QTableView (с моделью данных QSqlRelationalTableModel) при клике на поле с внешней связью в строке открывать внешн. связанную таблицу

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

То есть как при клике мышкой на поле в строке QTableView открыть связанную таблицу в диалоге, выбрать другое значение и подставить в данное поле QTableView.

Поле связано через setRelation (конечно же).

И еще вопрос 2 как скопировать такую строку.

И к сожалению вопрос надо рассматривать для 3 разных стратегий редактирования (OnFieldChange, OnRowChange, OnManualSubmit).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318914/qsqlrelationaltablemodel-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/1319280#1319280

Comment: Посмотрел ссылку и понял, что вы не внимательно читали мои вопросы. В примере по ссылке есть добавить запись и удалить запись, а с этим никаких проблем нет (ни у кого)

Comment: Ещё раз вопрос 1 - как в имеющейся записи установить новое значение (для поля с внешней связью)

Comment: Вопрос 2 - как скопировать строку, где можно быть поле с внешней связью